# Android split screen horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a screen that is split in half equally horizontal. My code works but I want to have a line that's about 1dp that shows the split. What can I do to add this?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/commerce_divider"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/apple">
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/white"></LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a View between both layouts with a height of **1dp**:

```
<view
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />
```

So, change your code to be:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/commerce_divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/apple"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

    <view
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"></LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```